# How can I recreate a corridor from a picture?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm making a game which display pics to show the player where he is. I want to use pictures of my surrounding in it, but add some 3d elements. I'm a total beginner with blender and I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paQV9QOxIto). Sadly the video is not about how he turned the picture to a 3d space, I'd like to know how he made that. making a light 3d environment (no big extrusion) from a picture of a corridor or a room. I want to make this so I can add elements in the space and re export it as a picture. (I know I could use a picture editing software but first I want to learn blender and in this scenario I want to be able to really have full control on the environment). Do you know the name of this technic or a link to a tutorial video ?

Comment: You can either try to recreate the 3D space from the perspective lines of your photo, to do that there are some apps like Fspy. Or you can recreate a 3D space that approximately looks like your photo, then unwrap the faces and then project the images on the surface. It's not as precise as the first method but easier imho, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: it seems that there wasn't any softwares used to achieve this and in comparison with other tutorials, there wasn't any extruding or 3d sculpting involved when creating the walls, roof, and floor and that's what I'm looking for since I'm not looking for a precise 3d space, just recreate quickly the place with perspective then adding a 3d model downloaded on internet too add it in the middle of the room

Comment: So I've watched the video again, please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the video he imports the image with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Image > Image As Planes* (don't forget to disable the *Show Backface* option later), then in *Edit* mode he cuts it with the *Knife* tool along the surfaces:

[image]

Then select a part and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate as a new object:

[image]

Then in *Edit* mode rotate 90° so that it is flat on Z, and scale so that it has approximately the right proportion, cut some edge loops or subdivide in order to untwist the image texture:

[image]

And so on for the other parts in order to rebuild about the same perspective as the corridor:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much